# ntopng error: segmentation fault

Tags: macos

I want to use ntopng to monitor my internet availability. I installed it following the instructions shown [here](http://www.ntop.org/ndpi/running-ntopng-and-ndpi-on-macosx/#) and [Run ntopng](http://linoxide.com/monitoring-2/ntopng-network-monitoring-tool/). However I'm getting the following error:

...(some messages here)
`07/Jan/2015 11:22:00 [Ntop.cpp:206] Welcome to ntopng i386 v.1.2.1 (r1.2.1) - (C) 1998-14 ntop.org
07/Jan/2015 11:22:00 [PeriodicActivities.cpp:53] Started periodic activities loop...
Segmentation fault`

I compared what I got with the text given in the first link, and everything is ok except that at the end I don't know why I'm shown: `Segmentation fault` instead of

```
12/Sep/2014 08:32:34 [NetworkInterface.cpp:800] Started packet polling on interface en0 [id: 1]...  
12/Sep/2014 08:32:34 [NetworkInterface.cpp:800] Started packet polling on interface en1 [id: 3]...  
12/Sep/2014 08:32:34 [NetworkInterface.cpp:800] Started packet polling on interface lo0 [id: 5]...
```

as shown in the first link. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try running it with elevated permissions? `sudo`

Comment: @ecnepsnai I typed in `sudo ntopng`